# Normalizing a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

Let the basis $B = \{1,x,x^2\}$ which is orthogonal.

Now, I've seen the following:

$$\|1\| = \sqrt {\langle 1,1\rangle} = \sqrt {4\cdot 1\cdot 1} = 2 $$
$$\|x\| = \sqrt {\langle x,x\rangle} = \sqrt {2\cdot 1\cdot 1} = \sqrt 2 $$
$$\|x^2\| = \sqrt {\langle x^2,x^2\rangle} = \sqrt {1\cdot 1} = \sqrt 1 = 1 $$

And therefore, an **orthonormal basis** would be: $$B = \{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{x}{\sqrt 2}, x^2 \}$$

Questions:

1. Isn't $\{1,x,x^2\}$ already orthonormal?
2. Isn't the calculation of the norm wrong?

**EDIT:**
The inner product (for $V=\mathbb{R}_2[x]$) is:
$$\langle a_1 + b_1x + c_1x^2, a_2 + b_2x + c_2x^2\rangle = 4a_1a_2 + 2b_1b_2 + c_1c_2$$

Comment: How is the inner product  defined?

Comment: Let me edit please

Comment: An orthonormal base means all its elements have norm $1$ and are pairwiseorthogonal.

Comment: @jmiller are you sure you've written the definition of inner product right? I think it should be $\langle a_1 + b_1x + c_1x^2, a_2 + b_2x + c_2x^2\rangle = 4a_1a_2 + 2b_1b_2 + c_1c_2$

Comment: That's exactly what's written above, isn't it?

Comment: @5xum, for example, why is it:$$ \|1\| = \sqrt {\langle 1,1\rangle} = \sqrt {4\cdot 1\cdot 1} = 2$$. Where's the $4$ came from? it's unclear to me.

Comment: @no you have written $b_1$ instead of $a_2$

Comment: Corrected the typo.

Comment: @jmiller the definition of inner product should be provided for each space. In your case the definition of inner product in the space of 2-degree polynomials is such that it's provided. In another problem we can have a different definition for inner product. so I should say according to the definition of inner product, the answer of both of your questions is no. this `according to` is very important and should be included in the answer. because for any inner product space we should define the inner product

Comment: $\|1 \| = \|1+0x + 0x^2\| = \sqrt{\langle 1+0x + 0x^2,1+0x + 0x^2 \rangle} = \sqrt{4\cdot 1 \cdot 1 + 2\cdot 0\cdot 0 + 0\cdot 0} = \sqrt{4} = 2.$

Comment: @jmiller using the scalar product you described, and knowing that $1=1+0\cdot x + 0\cdot x^2$, it is obvious that $\langle1,1\rangle = 4\cdot 1\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 0\cdot 0 + 0\cdot 0 = 4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the definition $\langle a_1 + b_1x + c_1x^2, a_2 + b_2x + c_2x^2\rangle = 4a_1a_2 + 2b_1b_2 + c_1c_2$ is just a definition provided in the problem.For each inner product space we should define the inner product and then define normality and orthogonality based on the definition of the inner product.
So don't say where 2 or 4 comes from. That's just a definition.
For example the common definition of inner product in 3-D vector space is:
$\langle (x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)\rangle=x_1x_2+y_1y_2+z_1z_2$
but I can encounter with a 3-D vector space that has another definition for inner product:

Comment: Oh I see now.. Thank you!

Comment: An inner product is required to be positive-definite, but $\langle (x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)\rangle=x_1y_2+y_1x_2+z_1z_2$ isn't. For example $\langle (-1,1,0), (-1,1,0) \rangle = -2 < 0$.

Comment: ok @A.P. it was just an example and I only wanted to state that the inner product should be defined in the problem. and it's not always the same as the common definition you can edit my answer and add positive-definite example

Comment: $\langle (x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)\rangle=|x_1y_2+y_1x_2+z_1z_2|$ still isn't positive definite because $\langle (1,0,0), (1,0,0) \rangle = 0$ even though $(1,0,0) \neq (0,0,0)$. I added to my answer a characterisation for inner products on a finite-dimensional real vector spaces. You can use it to make up as many examples as you wish... :P

Answer (score 5):

The computation of the norm is indeed correct, given the inner product you described.

The vectors in $\{1,x,x^2\}$ are easily seen to be orthogonal, but they cannot form an ortho*normal* basis because they don't have norm $1$. On the other hand, the vectors in
$$
\left\{ \frac{1}{\|1\|}, \frac{x}{\|x\|}, \frac{x^2}{\|x^2\|} \right\} = \left\{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}, x^2 \right\}
$$
have norm $1$ and are orthogonal, so indeed they form an orthonormal basis.

---

Recall that an inner product on a real vector space $V$ is just a function
$$
\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \colon V \times V \to \Bbb{R}
$$
which for every $x,y,z \in V$ and $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ satisfies:

- $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle y,x \rangle$
- $\langle ax + by, z \rangle = a\langle x,z \rangle + b\langle y,z \rangle$
- $\langle x,x \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle x,x \rangle = 0$ iff $x = 0$

Given an inner product on $V$, one can define the associated norm $\| x \| = \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$.

Furthermore, one can prove that if $\dim_{\Bbb{R}} V = n$ is finite, then every inner product on $V$ is of the form
$$
\langle x,y \rangle_A = x^T A y
$$
where $A$ is the symmetric positive-definite $n \times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij} = \langle e_i,e_j \rangle_A$.

For example the Euclidean (i.e. usual) inner product corresponds to the identity matrix, while the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
corresponds to the inner product
$$
\langle x,y \rangle_A = 2x_1y_1 - x_2y_1 - x_1y_2 + 2x_2y_2 - x_3y_2 - x_2y_3 + 2x_3y_3
$$
(checking that this is indeed an inner product is a good exercise).

Comment: Fun fact: for any real invertible matrix $A$ the matrix $A^TA$ is positive-definite.