# inner product and hermitian scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

suppose $\underline x,\underline y\in\mathbb C^{n\times 1}$ then because the two vectors are in complex vector field, the definition of their inner product will be:
$$\langle\underline x,\underline y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i^*\qquad\text{* represents conjugate}$$
then it seems that the definition for hermitian scalar product of these two vectors is the same
$$\langle\underline x|\underline y\rangle=\underline x^T.\underline y^*=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i^*\qquad\text{T represents transpose}$$
Are `inner product` and `hermitian scalar product` the same concept in vector spaces defined on complex numbers field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scalar product is just another name for inner product. Let V be a complex vector space. A Hermitian inner
product on V is any function
$$\langle ,  \rangle : V × V \rightarrow \mathbb{C},$$
that satisfies [these axioms](http://www.math.umd.edu/~hking/Hermitian.pdf):

1. $$\langle u, v \rangle  = \langle v, u \rangle $$
2. $$\langle u + v, w \rangle  = \langle u, w \rangle  + \langle v, w \rangle  \text{ and}$$

   $$\langle u, v + w \rangle  = \langle u, v \rangle  + \langle u, w \rangle $$
3. $$\langle cu, v \rangle  = \overline{c} \langle u, v \rangle  \text{ and}$$

   $$\langle u, cv \rangle  = c\langle u, v \rangle .$$
4. $\langle u, u \rangle $ is a non-negative real number and $\langle u, u \rangle  = 0$ if and only if $\langle u = 0 \rangle $.

What you've defined is just an example of a Hermitian inner product.

Comment: $V\times V$ is cartesian product. right? and you mean hermitian inner product is a broad concept satisfying the above axioms. And what I have defined above as $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i^*$ is an example of inner product.

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375433/normalizing-a-basis#comment2800343_1375433) you see I've said that for any inner product space, we should define the inner product

Comment: Yes, $\langle x, y \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \bar{y_i}$ is just one of many inner products that can be defined on $\mathbb{C}^n$. In general, all inner products on $\mathbb{C}^n$  are of the form $\langle x, y \rangle = \bar{y}^T H x$ where $H$ is Hermitian positive-definite matrix.